# React.js hooks state is not updating

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a state named **stories** I am in each story there is a list of **apartments** and in each apartment, there is a list of **areas**. I am trying to add a new area in an apartment but it's **replacing** the existing data.
Here's the code that shows how I am adding apartment details in story

```
let story = stories.find((story) => story.sid == storyID);
    const storyWithDetails = {
      ...story,
      appartmentDetails: [
        ...story.appartmentDetails,
        {
          apartment_name: apratmentName,
          apartment_num: apratmentNum,
          apartment_type: apartmentType,
          areaDetails: [],
        },
      ],
    };
const otherStoris = stories.filter((story) => story.sid != storyID);
    const newStories = [...otherStoris, storyWithDetails];
    newStories.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.sid) - parseInt(b.sid));
    setStories(newStories);
```

Now I am trying to add the area by the following code but it's replacing the area not adding a new one. How to solve this?

```
let story = stories.find((story) => story.sid == storyIndex);
    let apartment = story.appartmentDetails.find(
      (apartment) => apartment.apartment_num == apartmentID
    );

    let apartmentWithArea = {
      ...apartment,
      areaDetails: [
        ...apartment.areaDetails,
        {
          area_name: areaName,
          areaImages: "",
        },
      ],
    };
console.log(apartmentWithArea);
```

**Edit**

If I try to initialize the state like this

```
const [stories, setStories] = useState([
    {
      name: "1st Story",
      sid: 1,
      appartmentDetails: [
        {
          apartment_name: "Dummy",
          apartment_num: "1",
          apartment_type: "",
          areaDetails: [{ area_name: "Bath", areaImages: "" }],
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);
```

and try to add new area  **apartmentWithArea** works fine but If I want to add 3rd area **apartmentWithArea** replace the second area.

Comment: Where do you use `storyWithDetails` and `apartmentWithArea` ?

Comment: storyWithDetails code is added but I am just trying to check apartmentWithArea in log for now

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example so others can test the problem?

Comment: The code looks like it actually adds a new area

Comment: Yeah that's the issue but its not adding its replacing

Comment: @Yousaf kindly check the updated code

Comment: I think the problem in this comparison story.sid == storyIndex, sid is not index, its like an id, you couldn't compare an id with index!

Comment: No. it is an index